# Bootstrap toggle pills not working in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add data-toggle pills from bootstrap in react. But it seems like it cannot even find id.

This is my example. Only Example1 is visible, pills not switching to Example2.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class  extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="nav-tabs">
                    <ul className="nav nav-pills">
                        <li className="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#example1">Example1</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#example2">Example2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div className="tab-content">
                        <div id="example1" className="example tab-pane fade in active">
                            <p className="text16">Someting</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="example2" className="otherexample tab-pane fade">
                            <p className="text16">Someting2</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any crucial mistake in this code. 
React
react-dom
bootstrap css
bootstrap js
jquery
Make sure you have these libraries and place the scripts in the correct order, mayby edit you post and add the scripts to it.

```
<ul className="nav nav-pills">
    <li className="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#example1">Example1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="##example2">Example2</a></li>
</ul>

<div className="tab-content">
   <div id="example1" className="tab-pane fade in active">
     <h3>Example1</h3>
       <p>Some content.</p>
</div>

    <div id="example2" className="tab-pane fade">
       <h3>Example2</h3>
          <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```